# How to access secrets when using flutter web with github actions

Tags: flutter, github-actions, flutter-web, secret-key

I have a flutter web app and for accessing the database I have hardcoded an APIKey in a `secrets.dart` file, And this works perfectly fine. I have added this file to `.gitignore` in order to prevent it from pushing it to version control. But when it comes to deploying the app using GitHub actions The script fails because it doesn't detect the secrets file.

I did look at the docs on [Encrypted secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets) from Github which basically allows storing the secrets.But it seems like those secrets are only accessible in the yml file.

I would like to know how can I use this secret in my app so that my script runs successfully and deploys the app.
Here is my folder structure

```
lib/
  services/
     database.dart /// this file uses the APIkey from secrets.dart
  secrets.dart /// contains the APIkey
```

One way to solve this issue I can think of is to use a `.env` file but I am not much familiar with How to add the secret keys in .env file through the CI script. I believe that would also solve my problem.

Heres my CI script

```
# This file was auto-generated by the Firebase CLI
# https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge
"on":
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: "12.x"
      - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
        with:
          channel: "master"
      - run: flutter pub get
      - run: flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
      - run: flutter build web --release
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
          firebaseServiceAccount: "${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_VOCABHUB_34C7F }}"
          channelId: live
          projectId: vocabhub-34c7f
        env:
          FIREBASE_CLI_PREVIEWS: hostingchannels
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can use your `secrets.dart` file while being ignored in the source control.

#### Here are the steps

1. In your local machine, encode the content of your `secrets.dart` using the **base64** command:

   ```sh
     base64 lib/path/to/secrets.dart
   ```
2. Copy and paste the output into your GitHub secrets, name it `$SECRETS_FILE_CONTENT` or whatever you want.
3. Add this CI step into your *yaml* script just before the `flutter pub get` step.

   ```yaml
     # other stuff ...
     - run: echo $SECRETS_FILE_CONTENT | base64 -d > lib/path/to/secrets.dart
       env:
         SECRETS_FILE_CONTENT: ${{ secrets.SECRETS_FILE_CONTENT }}
     - run: flutter pub get
     - run: flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
     - run: flutter build web --release
     # other stuff ...
   ```

To add the secret in the GitHub user interface, follow these steps:

[image: Click on the repository's Settings tab, click on Secrets, click "New repository secret", DO NOT USE "environment secrets" because it does not work]

[image: Fill in the name of the variable e.g. SECRETS_FILE_CONTENT and its value e.g. the base-64 encoded file contents]

Your secret should appear in the lower "repository secrets" half of the UI, it should NOT appear in the "Environment secrets" as those do not work with a simple `${{ secrets.name_of_variable }}`.

[image: The SECRETS_FILE_CONTENT variable name should now appear in the second box at the bottom]

To provide more context, here's what the "actions" file, e.g. .github/workflows/ci.yml in your repository, should look like:

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main, dev ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

  # Allows to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:
  
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Decode base64 secrets
        run: echo $SECRETS_FILE_CONTENTS | base64 -d > lib/path/to/secrets.dart
        env:
          SECRETS_FILE_CONTENTS: ${{ secrets.SECRETS_FILE_CONTENTS }}
      # … put your steps here
        run: flutter pub get
```

##### Edit

This is also the same process when hiding `google-services.json` when people work with firebase. Or with signing keys (`key.jks` or `key.keystore`).

Comment: Dang! that seems to be working. Can you please explain what this step is doing ```run: echo $SECRETS_FILE_CONTENT | base64 -d > lib/utils/secrets.dart``` is it creating a file with the content?

Comment: Yes. That line will decode and write the output into the file path specified.

Comment: Thank you so much this is one of the simplest and the most secure solutions (AFAIK) I have ever seen, I am not sure why no one mentioned this. Anyways I would like to offer you a bounty for this great answer, I will be waiting for two more days.

Comment: congratulations on the bounty

Comment: OH GOD. so many hours debugging this. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I had to use the following command :
$SECRETS_FILE_CONTENT | base64 -di > lib/utils/secrets.dart
Otherwise, base64 -d failed. The return message was : invalid input.

Comment: I wrote a blog post describing this approach https://medium.com/flutter-community/managing-secrets-in-an-open-sourced-flutter-web-app-8c2219ed72b9

Comment: silly question: why do you even need to base64 encode it? it doesn't really add anything in terms of security right?

Comment: @PjotrGainullin it's not for security. If you directly paste a dart code or any string with special characters and formatting (like any code), Github Action will not accept it. And the environment runner itself will throw invalid string format errors or something like that.

Comment: @PjotrGainullin base64 is like a very simple 1 line string avoiding any string formatting errors and allowing it to be accepted globally.

Comment: WTF! I assigned it to "Environment Secrets" and don't know why it can't be accessed from a github action. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Actually you can read secrets from `Environment Secrets` you just need to define the desired environment name within the job where you read them, with `environment` keyword like this 
`jobs:
  publish:
    environment: env_name`

Answer (score 34):

if you're using Environment Secrets rather than Repository Secrets, you should define what environment will u use, check this out

```bash
jobs:
  build:
    environment: **ENVIRONMENT NAME HERE**

    steps:
      - name: blah blah
        run: echo blah blah
```

---

## UPDATE (2022-08-09)

```bash
jobs:
    build:
    ...
    environment: Foo
    steps:
        - uses : actions/checkout@v3
        - name : Run some customized action
          env :
            a : ${{ secrets.Bar }}
            b : $ Mona  
            c : ${{ secrets.Lisa }}
          run : |
            echo $a 
            echo $b
            echo $c
```

There were a lot of updates since I answered,
so to summarize,
There are 3 secrets in GitHub now

1. Environments Secrets
2. Actions Secrets (Repository Secrets)
3. Dependabot Secrets

Dependabot is out of this range.

Environments Secrets are:

```
Settings -> Environments -> New Environments -> Environment Secrets
```

Actions Secrets are:

```
Settings -> Secrets -> Actions -> Repository Secrets
```

so if we want to access the environment's secret value logically, we need to know 2 arbitrary variables: Environment Name and Environment Secret Name, for example: `EnvironmentName.EnviromentSecretName.EnvironmentSecretValue`

As I wrote, `Foo` is `EnvironmentName`

and

`Bar` is `EnvironmentSecretName`

and

`Mona` is constant

and

`Lisa` is Actions(Repository) Secret Name

so that if we set Environment Secret as `Mark` and Repository Secret as `Twain`

the console output will be:

```
Mark

Mona

Twain
```

Additionally, GitHub will redact the secret value like "***"
consider https://zellwk.com/blog/debug-github-actions-secret/
URI to debug it.

Comment: Can you update the run command to access those variables?  `${{ env.XXX }` seems to only reference those I explicitly set with `env: ....`

Comment: you put me on the right track, thank you