# Github Actions environment variables not being set on Linux

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to set my Github secrets as `env` variables via Actions but for some reasons they aren't being set (Using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS).

```
name: My app

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]

env:
  JWT_SECRET_KEY: ${{ secrets.JWT_SECRET_KEY }}
  JWT_REFRESH_SECRET: ${{ secrets.JWT_REFRESH_SECRET }}
  MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING: ${{ secrets.MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING }}
  PLAI_APP_URL: ${{ secrets.APP_URL }}
  SENDGRID_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.SENDGRID_API_KEY }}

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: self-hosted

    steps:
    - name: check out latest repo
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:
        ref: main
    - name: Set up Python 3.10
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: "3.10"
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Workflow runs successfully without errors but when I check my variables via `env` they are not listed. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could follow the same idea as in "[Managing secrets in an open-sourced flutter web app](https://medium.com/flutter-community/managing-secrets-in-an-open-sourced-flutter-web-app-8c2219ed72b9)" from [Mahesh Jamdade](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8253662/mahesh-jamdade):

> 1. encode your confidential file to base64 and store the encoded output to GitHub secrets.
> 2. In your GitHub workflow decode the encrypted secret and convert it back to a file and then run your build scripts.

You can see an example in "[How to access secrets when using flutter web with github actions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67998780/6309)".
Example workflow: [`maheshmnj/vocabhub` `.github/workflows/firebase-hosting-merge.yml`](https://github.com/maheshmnj/vocabhub/blob/master/.github/workflows/firebase-hosting-merge.yml#L20-L22).

Comment: good idea. I didn't realise I can't persist environment variables post workflow.